# What set is this? Minecraft and Star Wars?

Tags: set-identification

We have these sets in the Lego box. No box or instructions. I tried looking up codes and can’t find them. The silver part is the most unique one I can find to help look for it. And I think we have a small starwars set too? [image]

[image]

Comment: Orange [fish](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=64648&colorID=4&in=A) isn't included in any SW set. It also doesn't come together with Pearl Dark Gray [beehive](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=35574&colorID=77&in=A). There's more than one set in here.

Comment: Yeah, that part I’m nearly positive is from Minecraft . I think the only starwars is one or two packs to the side with a small grey cup, hair and little gun

Comment: What do you find when you scan the QR code on the wrapper?

Comment: why am I seeing the "silver" part as black?

Answer (score 6):

I can find only one set that includes both [Minifigure, Weapon Gun, Blaster with Clip, Dark Bluish Gray](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15445) and [Fish, Orange](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64648) and that is [76942 Baryonyx Dinosaur Boat Escape](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76942-1).

[image: Photo of dinosaur escape set]

That blaster kind of resembles a Star Wars element and I think I see a lightsaber also; but there is a lightsaber in this Dinosaur Escape set as well and the blaster only appears in one Star Wars set.

Comment: I don’t recall having this set, but we do have that tinny Dino, and the hair looks similar. We did have some Jurassic park sets  years ago.

Answer (score 6):

The [Pearl Dark Gray Beehive](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=35574&colorID=77&in=A)

and bag #2 with [Bright Light Orange Arch 1 x 4 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6182&colorID=110&in=A)

are from
[11015: Around the World](https://brickset.com/sets/11015-1/Around-the-World)
[image]

The bag on the upper right is from

[21164: The Coral Reef](https://brickset.com/sets/21164-1/The-Coral-Reef)

[image]

- [Minifigure, Weapon Sword Pixelated (Minecraft)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18787&idColor=115#T=C&C=115)
- [Technic, Axle 5L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32073&idColor=3#T=C&C=3) in yellow